# convert characters using PHP

Tags: php, html-entities

how do i convert below text to something like "Växjö" using PHP?

```
V&#xe4;xj&#xf6;
```

I have tried

```
html_entity_decode(preg_replace("/U\+([0-9A-F]{4})/", "&#x\\1;", $text), ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8')
iconv(mb_detect_encoding($text, mb_detect_order(), true), "UTF-8", $text)
```

Comment: Are you wanting to display `Växjö` or replace the entity codes with their respective characters, so the string actually *becomes* that data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any PHP version from 5.0 onwards should be fine with...

```
$decoded = html_entity_decode('V&#xe4;xj&#xf6;', ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
```

Demo here - http://3v4l.org/DZc59

Comment: From 5.4 you don't even need the 2nd and 3rd args

Answer (score 0):

```
echo html_entity_decode('V&#xe4;xj&#xf6;', ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```